# Is there a way to stop python from limiting the string representation of an object?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Basically I want to save off the string representation of a scikit learn pipeline so I know exactly what created the data.  However when trying to get the repr() or str() representation, python is limiting the size with a ...

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('ngrams', Pipeline([
        ('count_vectorizer1', CountVectorizer(max_features=200, token_pattern=r'(?u)\b\w+\b')),
    ])),
    ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=2000, n_jobs=5))
])

print str(pipeline)
print repr(pipeline)
```

Output:

```
Pipeline(steps=[('ngrams', Pipeline(steps=[('count_vectorizer1', CountVectorizer(analyzer=u'word', binary=False, decode_error=u'strict',
        dtype=<type 'numpy.int64'>, encoding=u'utf-8', input=u'content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=200, min_df=1,
        ngram_range=(1, 1), preproc...n_jobs=5,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False))])
Pipeline(steps=[('ngrams', Pipeline(steps=[('count_vectorizer1', CountVectorizer(analyzer=u'word', binary=False, decode_error=u'strict',
        dtype=<type 'numpy.int64'>, encoding=u'utf-8', input=u'content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=200, min_df=1,
        ngram_range=(1, 1), preproc...n_jobs=5,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False))])
```

Notice the ... in both cases.   Is there a way to tell python not to do this?

Comment: one possible way is to create your own Pipeline class that inherits from the existing Pipeline class but overrides the `__str__` and/or `__repr__` methods.

Comment: If I do that I would have to override the string class for every single type of object in the pipeline as well.  Surely python has a way to tell it to not do this.

Comment: There might be a way ... however, i don't think you'd need to do it for other objects as well, since you can return whatever you want in the methods

Comment: Why not just examine `pipeline.steps` directly?

Comment: pipelines can be nested, so would run into the same issue.

Comment: the pipelines being nested is why looking at pipeline.steps doesn't work.

Comment: The truncation occurs within sklearn's custom "pretty-printer" function, [`sklearn.base._pprint`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/base.py#L148). If you're really motivated you could subclass `Pipeline` and override its `__repr__` method, e.g. using a modified version of the `_pprint` function linked above. Is it really worth the effort?

Comment: unfortunately yes, it is very important.  ugg it is all hard coded.

Comment: @ali_m  you are definately correct.   I went in and just modified that line in my python install and it fixed it.  I will probably just use that solution for now and maybe open an issue with scikit to allow us to specify this.  Go ahead and add it as an actual answer

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure those are using NumPy's stringify.

Try:

```
import numpy
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.nan)
```

somewhere before your prints.

EDIT: Nope, my mistake, we're talking sklearn, not scikit itself.  sklearn's got its own base objects, and it's BaseEstimator that's clobbering your strings.

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/base.py#L111

line 142, in the _pprint function (which is used by BaseEstimator's `__repr__` in line 274).  The child objects inherit that straight from the base, so should just be able to override the one function.

Comment: this did not make a difference
tried both numpy.nan and threshold = 10000000000

Comment: You may want to specify where you put it for it to "not make a difference," as the following code uses exactly the technique I described: https://github.com/WilliamQLiu/python-examples/blob/master/sklearn/nytimes_article.py -- knowing what specifically was tried means we can troubleshoot further from there.  (And you did specifically import numpy first, correct?)

Comment: Numpy's print options are irrelevant since none of the objects that are being printed are numpy arrays. Have you actually tried your proposed solution?

Comment: There are only 2 places you can put it, before or after you create the pipeline.  neither worked.

Comment: @ali_m is right, but for the wrong reason.  NumPy's print options affect *all* NumPy objects.  Both Pipeline and CountVectorizer extend  sklearn's BaseEstimator.  BaseEstimator's `__repr__` uses its internal `_pprint` method, and `_pprint` internally sets NumPy's print options.  But I misread the code to `_pprint`, and was too hasty: the set_printoptions isn't the limitation.  It's a hard-coded 500 characters in BaseEstimator's _pprint: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/base.py#L111 line 142.  That's what you'd have to override. Editing answer to reflect.

Comment: any idea how I would override that on the fly?  or is the only way to actually go change it in my python libraries?

Comment: I figured it out.  I just define my own function and then open up that package and replace it in my script.